# How to make Google Polymer Single Page Apps with iron-pages router crawl-able by Search Engines

Tags: google-app-engine, seo, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a Single Page App that uses Google Polymer 1.0 hosted on Google App Engine. It uses iron-pages as the router, and loads contents in an AJAX manner. The landing page has hashbang (#!) links to child pages where content is then loaded on demand.

How can I make this web app SEO friendly? Google Webmaster Tools doesn't seem to be able to index the content. I've read about PhantomJS but unfortunately many claimed that it doesn't work with Google App Engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uncommon request, but can you share a URL Google cannot index? We (Google) render the content under every URL, it's very surprising to me we cannot index yours.

Comment: Hi. The test site that I've setup is at http://internal-koqa-tst.appspot.com/. Do I need to use the HTMLUnit method instead or would GoogleBot be able to detect that it is an AJAX application and index the site appropriately?

Comment: See also https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.at/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html